# Rounding datetime in tsql

Tags: t-sql

These are the values I have:

```
DECLARE @temp2 DATETIME = '9/1/2016 09:30:29.499 AM'; --rounded to '2016-09-01 09:31:00.000'
DECLARE @temp3 DATETIME = '9/1/2016 09:30:29.496 AM'; --rounded to '2016-09-01 09:30:00.000'
```

I want to round the miliseconds to seconds and the seconds to minutes, so that if there are 30 or more seconds, add one minute, and if the miliseconds are 500 or greater than 500, add one second. And this is how I've been trying to do it:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 0, DATEADD(MI, DATEDIFF(MI, 0, DATEADD(S, 30, CAST(@temp AS DATETIME2(0)))), 0))
```

As you can see, '9/1/2016 09:30:29.499 AM' gets rounded to 09:31, when it should get rounded to 09:30. I know that this happens because of the way SQL server handles miliseconds. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [DATETIME2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677335.aspx) by default - it has more accuracy, for no more storage space. DATETIME is only accurate to ~ 3.33ms but DATETIME2 allows for much more accuracy (100 nanoseconds) and avoids the rounding issue you are seeing.

You can also control the precision of a DATETIME2 (see above MSDN link)

Answer (score 0):

You can try convert

```
DECLARE @temp2 DATETIME = '9/1/2016 09:30:29.499 AM'; --rounded to '2016-09-01 09:31:00.000'
DECLARE @temp3 DATETIME = '9/1/2016 09:30:29.496 AM';

SELECT convert(datetime,CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @temp2, 120))
--SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), @temp3, 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily because you are specifying `datetime` as your initial variable declaration.

But assuming that your source data was `datetime2`, you would also face issues because you are using `datetime(0)` in your `select`, which means `0` fractional seconds.

So at present, your calculation steps are as follows:

1. `declare 09:30:29.499 as datetime` results in `09:30:29.500` as datetime can only handle times to the nearest 3 milliseconds.
2. `cast 09:30:29.500 as datetime(0)` rounds off the fractional seconds for `09:30:30`.
3. you add `30` seconds to it so `09:30:30` becomes `09:31:00`.

If your source data is held in `datetime` you will never receive a value with `498` or `499` milliseconds as `datetime` does not support that level of precision, so you don't need to worry about this.

If you *are* receiving dates with `498` or `499` level precision, you can change your `cast(@temp as datetime(0))` to `cast(@temp as datetime(6))` or whatever precision you require and your script will return the correct roundings.